# select one output query SPARQL

Tags: select, sparql, dbpedia

I've written this query in sparql:

```
SELECT ?spouse
WHERE {
dbr:Zach_Galifianakis dbp:spouse ?spouse.
}
```

and I have this output:

```
2012
""@en
"Quinn Lundberg"@en
```

(https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fspouse%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0Adbr%3AZach_Galifianakis+dbp%3Aspouse+%3Fspouse.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on)

**I don't understand how to select only the name "Quinn Lundberg"@en. I've tried using FILTER clause but it doesn't work.**

Comment: what do you mean by "select"? The query returns exactly what it does, there are 3 RDF triples in the dataset matching the triple pattern of your SPARQL query - that's just a matter of data quality issues in DBpedia. Indeed you could filter on something, but what? And there is no guarantee that the workaround does work for your next query.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but that's exactly the point where a human decision is needed unless you have a bunch of weird data cleansing patterns. Like in your example indeed you could skip i) numbers and ii) empty string literals, but that is just a subset of possible errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a generic solution, but this will fetch only the name for your case:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
dbr:Zach_Galifianakis dbp:spouse ?spouse.
FILTER (strlen(str(?spouse)) > 0 && lang(?spouse) = 'en')
}
```

[Output](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0Adbr%3AZach_Galifianakis%20dbp%3Aspouse%20%3Fspouse.%0D%0AFILTER%20%28strlen%28str%28%3Fspouse%29%29%20%3E%200%20%26%26%20lang%28%3Fspouse%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on)